# Simple redirect from example.com/index to example.com using web.config file

Tags: wordpress, web-config, redirect

I've restructured a WordPress site that's hosted on a Windows server, so I'm trying to redirect with a web.config file. I've tried dozens of variations from examples and I can't make it work. I know the solution is simple. But nothing worked for me.

Please, someone, give me a solution to redirect my site from example.com/index to example.com.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it on your DNS zone editor in your hosting admin panel.